# Raspberry Pi 4 Ubuntu 19.10 cannot enable cgroup memory at boostrap

Tags: raspberrypi, 19.10, arm64

On a Raspberry Pi 4, on a vanilla downloaded [19.10](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/19.10/release/ubuntu-19.10-preinstalled-server-arm64+raspi3.img.xz?_ga=2.48413414.15155891.1573916762-713940830.1554698813) image of Ubuntu 19 arm64, I failed trying to enable cgroup memory, needed for Kubernetes.

I created (because I don't understand well the real one, I think the 4th)

- `/boot/cmdline.txt`
- `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`
- `/boot/firmware/btcmd.txt` (modified)
- `/boot/firmware/usercfg.txt` (modified)

to append:

```
cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1
```

but in vain.

If I check `cat /proc/cgroups` the cgroup memory is disabled.

If I check `cat /proc/cmdline` there isn't.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've just had this exact problem after picking up a new rpi4 on Ubuntu 19.10. After a quick poke...

The `/boot/firmware/README` file appears to detail the updated boot process. The second step in the process is to load `/boot/firmware/config.txt` which specifies `/boot/firmware/nobtcmd.txt` as the current `cmdline`.

So modify `/boot/firmware/nobtcmd.txt` and append: `cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1`. Reboot and `cat /proc/cmdline`

I wouldn't be surprised if some magic (maybe enabling BT?) changes the cmdline to `/boot/firmware/btcmd.txt` so it might be worth adding the change to that file too.

Comment: This answer has valuable information also for ubuntu 21.10 on RPi: **Read `/boot/firmware/README`**. I read there that I had to edit /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt in ubuntu 21.10 for changing the kernel command line, and it worked!

Answer (score 19):

Following @kremerol solution, I was able to get my RPI 4 with Ubuntu 20.04 working.

1. Run `sudo nano /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`
2. Edit the default file to look like below.

   ```
    net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait fixrtc
   ```

   **NOTE:** These are the 3 settings to add:

   - `cgroup_enable=cpuset`
   - `cgroup_enable=memory`
   - `cgroup_memory=1`
3. Save the file and reboot and the node status will change to ready.
4. You can check the status by running `sudo microk8s.kubectl get nodes`

Comment: /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt is still the correct file to edit if you want to edit the kernel command line in ubuntu 21.10.

Answer (score 4):

On Raspbian I had to add the following in `/boot/cmdline.txt`

```
cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory
```

You must add this to the end of the existing line; if you add it at the bottom of file in a new line it doesn't work.

Comment: specific to Rasbpian

Comment: This solution fixed my Raspberry Pi Zero W

Comment: This file does not exist in ubuntu distributions for Raspberry Pi. See other answers for ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

On my Raspberry Pi 4 (`ubuntu-server-20.10`/`arm64`) I had to append the following lines to `/boot/firmware/cmdline.txt`:

`cgroup_enable=memory cgroup_memory=1`

Comment: I believe you have to extend the existing line in this file, not add another line. But I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're using an external USB disk with a microsd as boot device? In that case, the change must be done in the microsd partition and not in the USB.

Comment: I'm using the microsd slot available in the raspberry as a primary storage, attaching that sd to the pc i can see 2 partitions: boot and another one not readable from windows, i think the os one. Maybe i miss some basics.

Answer (score 0):

Reading in the boot partition the `config.txt` the settings of `cmdline` point to a file `nobtcmd.txt`, which is exactly what I can see at runtime from `/proc/cmdline`. Changed inside that and now it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

Before I tried these solutions which involve editing /boot/firmware/cmdline.txt or any other mentioned file, I tried first with installing cgroup-lite via apt-get.
This seemed to do the trick as well.

Docker: Version Groovy Gorilla 20.10.6
Ubuntu version 20.10
Pi 4: 8GB ARM64

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner to enable cgroup support in Raspberry Pi OS. Remember, you must reboot after running this command.

```
sudo sed -i '$ s/$/ cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory/' /boot/cmdline.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you load up the SD card on a Windows machine, there are a few drives mounted (don't format them again when windows offers to).

In the drive labelled **ubuntu-seed**, not ubuntu-boot you will find the cmdline.txt file to append `cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory`

Answer (score -1):

If you need to automate it

```
sed -e '1s/$/ cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory/' -i /boot/cmdline.txt
```

This appends `cgroup_enable=cpuset cgroup_memory=1 cgroup_enable=memory` at the end of the first line of `/boot/cmdline.txt`

Comment: No file named `/boot/cmdline.txt` exists in ubuntu distributions for Raspberry Pi.